# Why is Pipenv failing to found package on pypiserver local repo?

Tags: python, installation, pipenv, pypiserver

I have a pypiserver running locally with one package already deployed. The server is responding on localhost:8080 and i can see and download the package manually.
But every time I try to install the package through pipenv it can't find it :( Any help would be appreciated ;)

$ **pipenv install invault --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080**

Installing invault...

Error:  An error occurred while installing invault!

Error text: Looking in indexes: http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080/simple

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement invault (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for invault

[image]

✘ Installation Failed

Comment: have you found the solution?